# where to put live() to make this jquery crossfade work

Tags: jquery, live, addclass, removeclass

i have this jquery crossfade that is working for the most part

except it seems i need to use the live() function since the class "active" is being added to a list item element via the code.

i am not sure where to put the live() function in my code so this works.

heres my jquery:

```
$('.photo-thumbs ul li a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var next = $(this).parent('li').index();

    $('.photo-main ul .active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('.active');
    $('.photo-main ul li:eq('+next+')').fadeIn(1000).addClass('.active');

});
```

heres my html:

```
    <div class="photo-main">

        <ul>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/dummy1-l.jpg);"></li>
        <li class="active" style="background-image: url(images/dummy2-l.jpg);"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/dummy3-l.jpg);"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/dummy4-l.jpg);"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/dummy5-l.jpg);"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="photo-thumbs">

        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="background-image: url(images/dummy1-s.jpg);"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="background-image: url(images/dummy2-s.jpg);"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="background-image: url(images/dummy3-s.jpg);"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="background-image: url(images/dummy4-s.jpg);"></a></li>
        <li style="margin-right: 0px;"><a href="#" style="background-image: url(images/dummy5-s.jpg);"></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>
```

heres my css:

```
.listing-page .left .photo-main {
    width: 630px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.listing-page .left .photo-main li {
    width: 630px;
    height: 350px;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display: none;
}
.listing-page .left .photo-main .active {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
}
.listing-page .left .photo-thumbs li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.listing-page .left .photo-thumbs li a {
    display: block;
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.75;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.listing-page .left .photo-thumbs li a:hover {
    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

it seems that half the time the old LI does not fade out, and sometimes it switches to the wrong LI.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do.  Your code looks like it's trying to fadeOut the previously active li and then fadeIn the one that was clicked on.  But I don't see how one could click on something that wasn't already visible.  Can you describe in words like this what you're trying to accomplish on a click?

Comment: when you click on an LI within the "photo-thumbs" div, it should fade out the current LI within the "photo-main" div, and fade in the LI with the same index that was clicked in the "photo-thumbs" div. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `live`. You are just using an extra `.` in front of the class name:

```
$('.photo-main ul .active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('.active');
                                                       ^
$('.photo-main ul li:eq('+next+')').fadeIn(1000).addClass('.active');
                                                           ^
```

Get rid of the `.`s and your code should work just fine.

Comment: No problem. The simple problems are always the most difficult ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to tell what problem you're trying to solve here, but `.live() is` not needed for the active class in this code because you're not running selector queries involving .active ahead of time - you're only running them when you need them.  The only selector that is being run ahead of time here is the one that assigns the click handler and that doesn't specify the `.active` class.

If you want more specific help, you'll have to clarify what the problem is.

Also, `.live()` is no longer recommended.  One should use `.on()` (v1.7+) or `.delegate()` (before v1.7).

Based on the clarification of your question, I think you just need to remove the periods in front of the class name in `addClass()` and `removeClass()` so the code looks like this:

```
$('.photo-thumbs ul li a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var next = $(this).parent('li').index();

    $('.photo-main ul .active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');
    $('.photo-main ul li:eq('+next+')').fadeIn(1000).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: check out my OP, i posted the rest of my code and more details. thank you.

Comment: @scarhand - I asked a question about what you're trying to accomplish in a comment to your OP.

Comment: @scarhand - OK, I added more to my answer.  I think you just need to remove the extra periods in the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` method calls.